# PHP session files have permissions of 000 - They're unusable

Tags: php, permissions

I kept having issues with a Document Management System I'm trying to install as, at the first step of the installation process, it would error with:

```
Warning: Unknown: open(/tmp/sess_d39cac7f80834b2ee069d0c867ac169c, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
```

I looked in /tmp and saw the sess_* files have the following permissions

```
---------- 1 vanced vanced 1240 Jan 20 08:48 sess_d39cac7f80834b2ee069d0c867ac169c
```

All the session files look like this. So obviously, they're unusable by PHP and it's causing me lots of problems.

How can I get PHP to set the correct permissions? I've tried changing the directory which php.ini uses to /tmp/phpsessions and the same thing occurs. The directories are `a+rwx`.

Comment: Why is the php session file being created under the user ID? You running under cgi-bin/phpsuexec or something similar?

I suspect something is changing your default umask.

Answer (score 1):

The `/tmp` folder is a default placeholder for session files.  Better use your own custom session folder

If Your host has allowed `.htaccess` overrides permission, you can place the following directive in your `.htaccess` under `public_html` or `httpdocs` folder

```
php_value session.save_path '/yourpath/sessionfolder'
```

If you are NOT running `php` in `suphp` mode, Make sure the folder is writable by others (`777`)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a special `umask` setting for this account?  It looks like somewhere, someone may have set it improperly.   It should return something like:

```
% umask
0022
```

Comment: How can I check this? The 'vanced' user has no shell as I didn't allow it when creating the hosting account on my VPS (WebHost Manager)

Comment: I enabled shell access, switched users and checked the umask. It's 0022. The problem, however, is still occurring.

Answer (score 0):

To find the umask of a running process:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165212/linux-getting-umask-of-an-already-running-process

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the **umask** in the actual application.

Find the index.php or bootstrap file, and add at the top:

```
umask(0022);
```